# Sending copy of confirmation email on particular amount of products (Magento)

Tags: email, magento

I'm building a webshop with just 2 simple products. (ID 1 and ID 2)

When a customer does a purchase, he receives a confirmation email with order info.
Also, the store where he wants to pick up the products receives an email with order info.

Now I want to build in an extra function:
An extra email with order info needs to be send to my email when a customer purchases ten or more of product with ID 1 or one or more of product with ID 2.

I am completely new to Magento and where to find the correct files to customize. So I hope someone can help me getting this to work! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an observer for this

**/app/etc/modules/Yournamaspace_Orderhook.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yournamaspace_Orderhook>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Yournamaspace_Orderhook>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/community/Yournamaspace/Orderhook/etc/config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yournamaspace_Orderhook>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Yournamaspace_Orderhook>
    </modules>

<global>

    <models>           
        <orderhook>
            <class>Yournamaspace_Orderhook_Model</class>
        </orderhook>
    </models>

    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <auto_email_order>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>orderhook/observer</class>
                    <method>implementOrderEmail</method>
                </auto_email_order>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>

</global>
```

Create observer file

**app/code/community/Yournamaspace/Orderhook/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Yournamaspace_Orderhook_Model_Observer
{
    public function implementOrderStatus($event)
    {

     // implement your code here for email order to speacific email address with your template
        $order = $event->getOrder();


        return $this;
    }

   }
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this, named 'QuantityMail_Orderhook'. I'm also not known with the php syntax of Magento. How can I check the productcount for example?